# How do I convert a date like this /Date(1606867200000)/ to a string in format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using Bootstraptable and want to convert a date column to a British formatted date string.
If I do not change the value the table displays dates as /Date(1606867200000)/

I've set the column with a data-formatter = "dateFormatter"

My formatting function is

```
function dateFormatter(value) {
    if (value == "" || value == null) {
        return "-";
    } else {
        console.log(value);
        return value.toLocaleString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' });
    }
}
```

I've tried new Date(value) this gives invalid date.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the content `value` exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what your console is logging. If it's the entire " /Date(1606867200000)/" string or just the numeric value. You may need to parse out the value. They are "ticks" or milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970

 var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(1606867200000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date is I guess stored in Mongodb or some other kind of DB so please remove that formting and then convert to date like

```
const time = + "/Date(1606867200000)/".replace(/\D/g, "");
console.log( new Date( time ));
```

Comment: Yes... the data is returned from an MS SQL db via an Ajax call. Stripping out all but the digits allowed me to convert the date to a British Date string as required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess, problem is related to the format of input. You need to convert it do **Date** explicitly.

Try it:

```
const d = new Date(value); 
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
```

Comment: Thanks, I did say in my original post that I had tried new Date but got invalid date